# jQuery progress bar with status text

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

Is it possible to add status text in jQuery progress bar?

For example :

if i am selecting 3 files to upload i want to show the filename below the status bar
is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the one you are talking about is this one http://t.wits.sg/misc/jQueryProgressBar/demo.php then it is simple.

```
$("span.progressBar >span").prepend("<br/>");
```

you can test this directly on the page under the link above, using firebug ;-)

you may add  to get a centralized alignment.